# R: How can I install a specific release by install_github()?

Tags: r, devtools

If the current version of a package, gives some errors, users may prefer to install a specific release (e.g. version 1.0.1). What kind of *R* code can be used to achieve that?

Take for example for the release of the latest `OhdsiRTools` R packages:

https://github.com/OHDSI/OhdsiRTools/tree/v1.0.1

The command something like:

```
install_github("OHDSI/OhdsiRTools", ref = 'v1.0.1')
```

The code above is not correct. It only works for branches (e.g., `master` or `devA`). But the `devtools` package has functions to refer to releases.

Ideally I would refer to releases by their tag (but solution with commit ID would work too).

EXTRA BONUS: What code can install "latest" release. (but consider this a bonus question. The question about is the main one)

Comment: This might have been a problem in the past (I don't know), but as of November 2021 the `ref = ` syntax applies to tags as well.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to append tags for releases directly onto the name of the repository argument. So, `username/repo@releasetag` will work. Only use the parameter `ref = "devA"` when you need to refer to a specific branch of the git repository.

For your example, regarding [OhdsiRTools v1.0.1](https://github.com/OHDSI/OhdsiRTools/tree/v1.0.1), we have

we have:

```
devtools::install_github("OHDSI/OhdsiRTools@v1.0.1")
```

**Edit**

After toying around with `devtools` source, it has come to my attention that one can request the latest source with:

```
username/repo@*release
```

Hence, you could use:

```
devtools::install_github("OHDSI/OhdsiRTools@*release")
```

**End Edit**

**Outdated, see edit**

Unfortunately, to obtain the latest release tag, the work for that is a bit more complicated as it would involve parsing a response from the GitHub API. Here are some notes if you really do need the tagged version... You would have to parse JSON from:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/releases/latest
```

using either [`RJSONIO`](http://www.omegahat.org/RJSONIO/), [`jsonlite`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html), [`rjson`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html)

To extract `"tag_name"` from:

```
{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/OHDSI/OhdsiRTools/releases/2144150",
  "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/OHDSI/OhdsiRTools/releases/2144150/assets",
  "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/OHDSI/OhdsiRTools/releases/2144150/assets{?name,label}",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/OHDSI/OhdsiRTools/releases/tag/v1.0.1",
  "id": 2144150,
  "tag_name": "v1.0.1",
  "target_commitish": "master",
  "name": "Minor bug fix",
  "draft": false,
  "author": {
    "login": "schuemie",
    "id": 6713328,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/6713328?v=3",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/schuemie",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/schuemie",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/schuemie/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/schuemie/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/schuemie/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/schuemie/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/schuemie/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/schuemie/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/schuemie/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/schuemie/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/schuemie/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "prerelease": false,
  "created_at": "2015-11-18T00:55:28Z",
  "published_at": "2015-11-18T06:35:57Z",
  "assets": [

  ],
  "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/OHDSI/OhdsiRTools/tarball/v1.0.1",
  "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/OHDSI/OhdsiRTools/zipball/v1.0.1",
  "body": "Fixed bug in `convertArgsToList ` function."
}
```

Above is taken from https://api.github.com/repos/OHDSI/OhdsiRTools/releases/latest

Comment: Thanks for improving the answer. I'm guessing that the first solution (`devtools::install_github("OHDSI/OhdsiRTools@v1.0.1")`) was updated after your edit because it uses the `@` syntax, but in your edit, you also include an asterisk (`devtools::install_github("OHDSI/OhdsiRTools@*release")`) Which is it? `@*` or `@`? With or without the asterisk?

Comment: @Dannid Both are correct. The `@v1.0.1` is hard coded whereas the latter `@*release` automatically gets the latest version, e.g. `v1.0.1`. Though, the **latest** release for this package haven't been updated since this question was posted. Unfortunately, only tags to the repo were added, c.f.  https://github.com/OHDSI/OhdsiRTools/releases

Answer (score 34):

For anyone who arrives here looking for how to install from a specific commit SHA, it's simply:

```
remotes::install_github("username/repository@commitSHA")
```

#### Example

Look for the SHA for the commit you want to install from the ['commits'](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext/commits/master?before=24e9cd059e599e1ce39bfaf3951d09cccc0aad99+35) page on github:

[image]

In this case the commit SHA is: `8bc79ec6dd57f46f753cc073a3a50e0921825260`, so simply:

```
remotes::install_github("wilkelab/ggtext@8bc79ec6dd57f46f753cc073a3a50e0921825260")
```